# How to configure SCDF Skipper to use pre-existing docker instance?

Tags: docker, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I'm currently evaluating the usage of Spring Cloud Data Flow for our infrastructure. We already use RabbitMQ and Kubernetes so that would be our target environment.

For local testing purposes I use dockerized MySQL and RabbitMQ and I want SCDF-Skipper to deploy the Stream-Services to my local docker instance so they can use the pre-existing MySQL and RabbitMQ-Containers (and I can manage and monitor everything in one single docker instance).

My first approach was to use Skipper and Dataflow Server from docker-compose but since I failed deploying something, I switched to use the jars following this tutorial:

https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/manual/

By now, deployment of the stream works but fails to connect to my preexisting, dockerized MySQL. That is because by default SCDF Skipper seems to deploy to an internal Docker-Instance.

So my question is:
Is there any way to configure SCDF Skipper to use the Docker-Instance on my local machine as deployment-target?

Answer (score 0):

After another iteration of research, I stumbled upon
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/#docker-stream--task-applications

Apparently, to use Skipper and Dataflow-Server from within Docker (DooD, Docker-out-of-Docker), you have to add another docker-compose.yml.

That does NOT solve how to use a pre-existing docker-instance when running Skipper locally from jar, but at least it enables me to run them as a container on a pre-existing docker and thus lets it use it as deployment-target.